# Distance calculation from 2 files in Excel using Python

Tags: python, distance

I want to write a program in Python to solve this problem. I have two excel files:

1. File1 with customer IDs and coordinates (Long, Lat) of various test
   points.
2. File2 containing all sites and their coordinates(Long, Lat).

I want to create a new column first file that shows the nearest site for each customer ID. The Customer Site ID is defined as: Min of distance from all the sites in 2nd File.

I have imported both excel files in pythons as separate Dataframes File1 and File2.
Till now I have been able to define function for Distance calculation. This is working fine.

```
def Distance(LatA,LongA,LatB,LongB):
    Distance = 6371 * np.arccos(np.cos(np.deg2rad(90 - LatA)) 
                        * np.cos(np.deg2rad(90 - LatB)) 
                        + np.sin(np.deg2rad(90 - LatA))
                        * np.sin(np.deg2rad(90 - LatB))
                        * np.cos(np.deg2rad(LongA - LongB))
                      )
    return Distance
```

Below code I have written for iterative distance calculation and saving it in new columns in File1 ('Min Distance' and 'Site ID').

```
File1['Min Distance']=1          # Define blank Column in File1
File1['Site_ID']=1               # Define blank Column in File1
L12={'MinDist':[1],'SiteID':[1]} # Define blank field
Dist_df=pd.DataFrame(L12)        # convert to DataFrame

for ind1,rw1 in File1.iterrows():
    for ind2,rw2 in File2.iterrows():
        DistA=0
        DistA=Distance(File1.Lat[ind1],File1.Long[ind1],File2.Lat[ind2],File2.Long[ind2])
        Dist_df.loc[ind2]=[DistA,File2.loc[ind2,'SiteID']]
    File1.loc[ind1,'Min_Distance':'Site_ID']= Dist_df[Dist_df['MinDist']==Dist_df['MinDist'].min()]
```

I keep getting below errors:

- ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing
- KeyError:'Min_Distance'

Any suggestions to correct the errors and improve the code.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, the fact that you're not following style conventions makes things more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

I can't do comments, but try this and let me know what problems you have:

```
File1['Min_Distance']=1          # Define blank Column in File1
File1['Site_ID']=1               # Define blank Column in File1
L12={'MinDist':[1],'SiteID':[1]} # Define blank field
Dist_df=pd.DataFrame(L12)        # convert to DataFrame

for ind1,rw1 in File1.iterrows():
    for ind2,rw2 in File2.iterrows():
        DistA=0
        DistA=Distance(File1.Lat[ind1],File1.Long[ind1],File2.Lat[ind2],File2.Long[ind2])
        Dist_df.loc[ind2]=[DistA,File2.loc[ind2,'SiteID']]
    File1.loc[ind1,['Min_Distance','Site_ID']]= Dist_df[Dist_df['MinDist']==Dist_df['MinDist'].min()].iloc[0,:].values
```

Edit: corrected some typos in yours (Min Distance and Min_Distance, added brackets to your loc)

Edit: have to set File1.loc[ind,[...]] = Dist_df[...]**.values**

Edit: added the iloc in '.min()].iloc[0,:].values' so you can handle two sites exactly the same distance from a user (just take the first)